# Use mysqli object in class, which should be stored in session - better approaches

Tags: php, class, session, mysqli

I'm working on a web application, which needs to be available in several languages. For every registered user I store the selected language in the database.

Moreover the logged in user can select a different language and then it should change on the fly, meaning the website should reload and be displayed in the new selected language.

The translation files are simple CSV files with key-value pairs (about 600 pairs for now).
I now implemented a class `Localization`, which loads the CSV file for the selected language into an array. An because I thought it would be better to not read the CSV file on every new page, I am storing the `Localization` object in the SESSION.

The problem now is that if the user changes the language I want to update the selected language in the database and also need to initialize the supported (selectable) languages meaning I need a mysqli connection.

```
class Localization
{
    private $mysqli; // cannot be serialized and stored in session
    private $language;
    private $supportedLanguages;

    public function __construct($language, $mysqli) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
        $this->initSupportedLanguages();
        $this->setLanguage($language);
    }

    [...]

    public function setLanguage($language) {
        if ($language != $this->language)
        {
            if ($this->isSupportedLanguage($language))
            {
                $this->language = $language;                
                set_current_user_language($language, $this->mysqli);
                // loads the csv file into an array
                $this->loadTranslation($language);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Language is not supported.";
            }
        }
    }

    private function initSupportedLanguages() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Sprache";
        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query))
        {
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                $this->supportedLanguages[$row['LanguageCode']] = $row['Name'];
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Could not create prepared statement.";
        }
    }
    [...]
}
```

Everything works fine, on the first page when object gets created. But if the user accesses the next page, the mysqli object cannot be accessed.

Unfortunately I found out, it is not possible to serialize the mysqli object and store it in the session, which caused the problem with not being able to access it.

I'm now asking for an approach to handle the database connection in a best practice way. 
To mention, other functions use a mysqli object added with the `require_once` functionality, but as far as i know it's not possible either to use `require` or `include` in a class.

Comment: It's possible to use `require()` or `include()` in a class. That only makes sense when loading classes, basically.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment I can't really figure out where to put the require_once(db_connection.php). If i put it before the class definition I can't use the mysqli object. If i put it in the class I get a parser error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I finally figured out how to do it.
I still have to use `require` inside every function I want to query the database, but i can live with that.
Another problem was, that I used `require_once` instead of `require` which is not working apparently.

```
public function setLanguage($language) {
    if ($language != $this->language)
    {
        if ($this->isSupportedLanguage($language))
        {
            $this->language = $language;
            require(PATH_INCLUDES . '/db_connect.php');
            set_current_user_language($language, $mysqli);
            $this->loadTranslation($language);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Language is not supported.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize resource object, it's a no sense.

In your case, just reopen the database connection if `$mysqli == null`.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I already figured that out... I have also written that I don't know how to open the database connection, because it's not possible to use `require`. But what I want to avoid is, to hardcode the connection in every function of the class.

Comment: You can use require. Anyway, I assume your MySQL connection is required by your application. Why this file is not included by your main app file/config ? `$mysqli` is set from the constructor, so your application may already have opened the connection.

Comment: I can't really figure out where to put the `require_once(db_connection.php)`. If i put it before the class definition I can't use the mysqli object. If i put it in the class I get a parser error.
In the rest of the application it is included.

Answer (score 0):

> An because I thought it would be better to not read the CSV file on every new page, I am storing the Localization object in the SESSION.

So you made your application to read a serialized file on every new page, which is all the same.

So you made your application more complex, consuming more  resources and put yourself in a trouble while gaining nothing.

This is why it is said that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score -1):

In these cases i am using the classmethods `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`

In the sleep method of the class i unset the variable which closes the connection

```
public function __sleep()
{
    unset($this->_mysqli);
}
```

In the wakeup method i reinitialise the connection the have it available at all times

```
public function __wakeup()
{
    $this->_mysql = new MysqliConnect(); //My custom mysqliwrapper
}
```

I hope this will help you out.

Further reading on sleep and wakeup [here](http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.magic-functions.php)